# 'Chicken' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently in the process of writing a larger program in python. It is a simple game, but I've got an Error. Can someone help me?

**Error**

```
          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kkuja/Desktop/game.py", line 36, in <module>
    MainWindow.MainLoop()
  File "C:/Users/kkuja/Desktop/game.py", line 17, in MainLoop
    self.chicken_sprites.draw(self.screen)
  File "C:\Users\kkuja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 475, in draw
    self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
AttributeError: 'Chicken' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

**Code**

```
import os, sys
import pygame

class Game:
    def __init__(self, width=640, height=480):
        pygame.init()
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode([self.width, self.height])
    def MainLoop(self):
        self.ChickenLoad();

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        self.chicken_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def ChickenLoad(self):
        self.chicken = Chicken()
        self.chicken_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(self.chicken)

class Chicken(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("chic.jpg")


 if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow = Game()
    MainWindow.MainLoop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see the instance variable, property or method `rect` in either the `Chicken` or the `Game` class.

Comment: i'm absolutely green... can you explain it?

Comment: You're accessing an object (instance) of the `Chicken` class. It has no member named `rect`. Because the base class (`Game`) does not define `rect` either, it cannot be found. The answer below defines the member in the derived class (in that example it's the `Block`).

Comment: Please **NEVER** change the topic of a question on StackOverflow! Create a new question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the function `self.chicken_sprites.draw(self.screen)` in your code `chicken.rect` is trying to be accessed, but you did not define it.

If you refer to the [official documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) you can find this piece of code:

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
    # and its x and y position
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
       # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

       # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
       # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
       self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
       self.image.fill(color)

       # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
       # Update the position of this object by setting the values of rect.x and rect.y
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

You do not set `self.rect` in your `Chicken`, it should look like this.

```
class Chicken(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("chic.jpg")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(); #here rect is created
```